# Sequences in $C(X)$ converging uniformly implies uniform boundedness and equicontinuity

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $X$ be a metric space and let $\{ f_n \}_{n \geq 1}$ be a sequence in $C(X)$. Show that if $\{ f_n \}_{n \geq 1}$ converges uniformly on $X$ then $\{ f_n \}_{n \geq 1}$ is both uniformly bounded and equicontinuous.

Could I get a hint?

Comment: Here's a hint: look at the definitions of uniform convergence, uniform boundedness and equicontinuity. Then, if you have a specific question, why the first implies the other two, you should ask again.

Answer (score 3):

**Hints**
Take a look at the definitions of uniform convergence, uniform boundedness and equicontinuity. In particular, uniform boundedness is easy to show (remember the fact, that convergent sequences are in particular bounded). The proof of equicontinuity is done by a standard $\frac{\varepsilon}{3}$-argumentation: $$|f_n(x)-f_n(y)| \leq |f_n(x)-f(x)|+|f(x)-f(y)|+|f_n(y)-f(y)|$$ where $f$ denotes the limit $\lim_{n \to \infty} f_n$

**Remark** Assume, $X$ is compact. In this case, one can apply Arzelà-Ascoli theorem to $A := \{f_n; n \in \mathbb{N}\} \cup \{f\}$. Note, that $A$ is sequentially compact, thus (relatively) compact.

Comment: Regarding 2: @junio didn't assume $X$ to be compact.

Comment: @kahen Thanks, you are right.

Comment: @saz: Can you explain how you knew to put $|f_n(x)-f_n(y)$| on the left hand side? I thought that since we are trying to show equicontinuity, we would have $|f(x)-f(y)|$ on the left hand side instead.

Comment: @SujaanKunalan We want to prove equicontinuity of the sequence $(f_n)_n$, i.e. we want to show that for any $\varepsilon>0$ there exists $\delta>0$ such that for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $|x-y| <\delta$, we have $$|f_n(x)-f_n(y)| \leq \varepsilon.$$ So it is not really surprising that we have to put $|f_n(x)-f_n(y)|$ on the left hand side, right?

Comment: @saz, Yes, you're right; that makes sense. Thanks for clarifying.